# guzzle3 add token Post Request

Tags: guzzle

I am working on a project using an old version of Guzzle (version 3), I'd like to add a token to the post request, can't find how to do it, I have looked on the doc there is no example for that , here is what I tried so far :

```html
<?php
$client = new Client();
$client->setDefaultOption('headers', array(
    'Authorization' => ['Bearer', $token] 
));
$req = $client->post($url);
$client->send($req)->getBody(true);
?>
```

```
$client->setDefaultOption('auth', array(null, 'Bearer'.$token ))
```

I keep getting : 
 Guzzle\Http\Exception\ClientErrorResponseException: Client error response [status code] 400 [reason phrase] Bad Request [url]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

```
`$client = new Client();
 $client->setDefaultOption('headers', array(
   'Authorization' =>  'Bearer '.$token,
 ));`
```

So instead of array in Authorization I sent a string that contains the token